# Issue with site collection restore form backup?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Hi im trying to restore  site collection PROD (70GB) in to UAT.  getting error "The site collection could not be restored. If this problem persists, please make sure the content databases are available and have sufficient free space"
so far i had done solution posted in here and also have more the 200GB of free space in UAT server drive still getting same error. appreciate your help .

************************ULS logs********************************
10/02/2014 22:38:01.60  PowerShell.exe (0x0334) 0x10F0  SharePoint Foundation   Database    tzkv    High    SqlCommand: 'proc_DeleteSite'     CommandType: StoredProcedure CommandTimeout: 0     Parameter: '@RETURN_VALUE' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: ReturnValue Value: ''     Parameter: '@SiteId' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '13a82a3d-0927-4dc0-afaf-35d1a9a1f665'     Parameter: '@ThresholdRowCount' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@RequestGuid' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '75557fb7-f78b-480b-a7a3-91921fa4518b' 75557fb7-f78b-480b-a7a3-91921fa4518b
10/02/2014 22:38:03.01  PowerShell.exe (0x0334) 0x10F0  SharePoint Foundation   Backup and Restore  aag1    High    VbackupRestore::RestoreSite, failed HR detected: -2147024858    75557fb7-f78b-480b-a7a3-91921fa4518b
10/02/2014 22:38:03.80  PowerShell.exe (0x0334) 0x10F0  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    The site collection could not be restored. If this problem persists, please make sure the content databases are available and have sufficient free space.0x81020099 75557fb7-f78b-480b-a7a3-91921fa4518b
10/02/2014 22:38:04.29  PowerShell.exe (0x0334) 0x10F0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  6tf2    High    The site collection could not be restored. If this problem persists, please make sure the content databases are available and have sufficient free space.   75557fb7-f78b-480b-a7a3-91921fa4518b
10/02/2014 22:38:04.34  PowerShell.exe (0x0334) 0x10F0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  91ux    High    Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL    75557fb7-f78b-480b-a7a3-91921fa4518b

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshooting:**

- Check the disk space on the SQL Server where LDF and MDF files are
  stored.
- Check the partition on the SQL SERVER in reference to
  data files.
- Make sure the content database has enough space
  allocated.
- Make sure the databases does not have restrictive
  growth
- Make sure to check the disk space on the SP server where
  restore is running.  Approximately it should 2 times the DB size.

**Resolution:**

- Go to “SQL Server Properties--Connections” and uncheck ‘Use query governor to prevent long-running queries’. Also, set “Remote query
  timeout” to 0.
- Stop and restart the "Windows SharePoint service Timer" 
  -Restart IIS

http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/the-site-collection-could-not-be.html#.VDMrefmSyQ8

Related Link:
http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/the-site-collection-could-not-be-restored-please-make-sure-the-content-databases-are-available-and-have-sufficient-free-space-sharepoint-orphaned-sites/

Another thing to try is to clear configuration cache as showing in the following link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx?Redirected=true

Another resolution is to run the following powershell script:

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase "Content_DB_Name";
$db.Repair($true);
$db.Update();
```

http://www.manvir.net/restore-spsite-the-site-collection-could-not-be-restored-if-this-problem-persists-please-make-sure-the-content-databases-are-available-and-have-sufficient-free-space-5/